When was extreme longevity of some species first suspected?
Although myths of extreme age in heroes and even ordinary humans seemed to have been common, it is only fairly recently that lifespans of centuries for Greenland sharks and Bowhead whales has been substantiated.
But did for example, native Americans who hunted Bowheads or the people who eat the Greenland shark suspect this at all? Sadly for the whales, the first clues of longevity was the discovery of antique harpoons in the bodies of recently killed whales. Then biochemically it was determined that Bowheads might reach well over 250 years, truly amazing for a creature who might be quite intelligent and perhaps even aware of human cultural changes, at least hunting methods of humans.
The Greenland shark is believed to reach 500 years and maybe outliers live, as amazing that 500 years is to contemplate, 600,700, maybe 1000 years?? But I suspect those who hunted them had no idea of this.
As for the very tall trees, I could imagine ancients who saw such grown trees did in fact suspect great age based on the rate at which trees seem to grow.

In the 1980-s. "Having hunted these whales for centuries, the Iñupiat are keen observers of the bowhead (Balaena mysticetus). Their tales recall whales that hunters had recognized by distinctive scars. In some cases, several generations of storytellers described encountering the same whale, leading to speculation that bowheads might live some 60 years... The new research was triggered by hunters finding ancient harpoon points in the foot-thick blubber of newly landed whales. Six points made of stone or ivory have turned up since 1981." Raloff.

@Conifold: That deserves to be an answer. The wisdom of what can be reasonably called indigenous scientists, even if that was not their primary occupation. If you are a hunter, the study of your prey is integral to what you are doing.
